# Word 2007 INCLUDEPICTURE behaves differently on different computers

Tags: ms-word

I have a word document with many pictures. The pictures are in a subdirectory below the document.
The Pictures are linked with an INCLUDEPICTURE Field. The path is set absolute.

```
{INCLUDEPICTURE "C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Word\\Grafiken_neu\\Titelbild.jpg" \* MERGEFORMAT \d}
```

If I take the document to a complete different computer to a completly different directory the pictures appear. The path from the original user is not accessible from the target computer.

I've tested in on different computers. The path of the picture is not changed, but word seems to guess  where the right pichture lies.

However one installation of word display only a small "red x"
The installation of Word is the same all over the company.

So I guessed that there is a setting for the intelligence of word to guess the right paths. But I haven't found it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved. 
Very tricky: 
The Path displayed is not necessarily the real path. In this case the images where on a path on the Network and the new user of the document had no access to the path.

It is very strange that Word displays the local-path of the creator, but not the URN.